# Parsing tab separated data

Tags: c++

I have a text file (~10GB) with the following format:

```
data1<TAB>data2<TAB>data3<TAB>data4<NEWLINE>
```

I want to scan through it and do processing only on `data2`. What is the best (fastest) way to extract `data2` in C++.

EDIT: Added NEWLINE

Comment: Are there any new lines? The easiest way is a line at a time.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood Yes there is new line.

Comment: @Ajay: How long is each `dataN` part? Is it fixed or variable?

Comment: @Xeo It is a word, hence a variable

Comment: I'm confused. Why not open the file, read a string, ignore the result, read whitespace, then read the next string?

Comment: Which OS are you working on? Given the size of your file how you access it may make a lot of difference to your performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file line by line.  For each line, split on the tab.  That will leave you with an array containing the fields, allowing you to work with the second field (data2).

Comment: That's clean, but does a lot of unnecessary work.  The question prioritises speed.

Comment: The only thing unnecessary is storing the other fields in the array versus throwing them away; this is roughly a constant memory expense, however.  What's faster, Tony D?  The cut suggestion below should be substantially slower (as cut will be taking a pass over the data, and you'll have to fork/exec to run cut, and then take a pass over its output)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a higher level tool like shell utilities:

```
cut -f2           # from stdin
cut -f2 <my_file  # from file
```

But nonetheless, you can do that with C++ as well:

```
void parse(std::istream& in)
{
    std::string word;
    while( in ) {
        std::cin >> word;  // throwaway 1
        std::cin >> word;  // data2
        process(word);
        std::cin >> word >> word;  // throwaway 3 and 4
    }
}

// ...
parse(std::cin);
std::ifstream file("my_file");
parse(file);
```

Comment: wow i love the cut solution.  if the poster insists on using C/C++ to do this, and cut is guaranteed to be on the system, they could just use popen("cut -f2 <my_file","r") to get a handle to the stream of desired data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, open a file stream (which should be able to handle 10gig files) and then just jump to after the first tab, which is a `'\t'`, read your data and then skip to the next newline and repeat.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::fstream fin("your_file.txt");

  while(fin){
    std::string data2;
    char sink = '\0';

    // skip to first tab
    fin.ignore(1024,'\t');

    fin >> data2;
    // do stuff with data2

    // skip to next line
    fin.ignore(1024,'\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the character by character scan consume more time.

Comment: I mean would a getline and strtok be more efficient

Comment: @Ajay: `getline` has to go through all those characters too. And so has `strtok`, so I'd guess no.

Comment: `sink` will never be `'\t'` or `'\n'`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Edited, forgot about whitespace skipping again, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: +1 That's the cleanest (and probably fastest) implementation possible for iostreams. If the performance is still a pain, then it's at least worth reimplementing with memory mapped file access and a pointer to scan... can be *much* faster sometimes (1-2 orders of magnitude, consider using madvice or similar to avoid hosing cache) but it all depends on your drives, cache and memory sizes etc..

Answer (score 1):

Read the file a line at a time. It's pretty straight forward parsing out the tabs from there. You could use something like `strtok()` or similar routine.

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is of a considerable size, you might consider using a technique that will allow you overlap your I/O with your processing. In response a comment, you mentioned you were working on linux. Provided you are using kernel 2.6 or later you might consider using Linux asynchronous I/O (AIO). Specifically you would use `aio_read` to queue up some read requests, then use `aio_suspend` to wait for one (or more) of the request to end. As requests complete you would scan through the buffers using a plain char* to locate the data you are interested in. For each piece of data you find you could at that point create a std::string (although avoiding copying may be beneficial) and process it. Once you have scanned a block you would requeue it to read another block from the file. You continue doing this until you have processed every block in the file.

The code for this method will be more complex than reading the file line by line, but it may be considerably faster.

Comment: "considerably faster"... not necessarily... the processing could easily be orders of magnitude faster than the I/O anyway (all depends on the hardware and exact approach to processing - std::strings are slower than in-place pointer/length handling), in which case the potential benefit from this is minimal. The event handling overheads could even make it slower.  It *is* worth trying if optimal performance is desired, but not with great expectations... ;-P

Comment: @Tony all good points. Geez, there's always one in the audience ;-)

Comment: Anyway, +1 for being the only one to present this approach. :-)

Comment: @Tony thanks. My experience has been that using C++ line by line I/O is quite slow. I guess there is a lot of copying going on (or something, I never felt inclined to investigate too much), so even if you processing is quite speedy (for example a checksum) you can still squeeze quite a bit of extra performance out of this technique. Of course, your mileage may vary!

Comment: well, `while (getline(std::cin, my_string)) ...` is slow (I haven't investigated either - strange as `my_string` should only reallocate a few times and that's the most obvious performance risk).  Anyway, `aio_read` reads a binary block, more comparable to `my_stream.read()`... not a function I have or have heard performance complaints about.  After these block reads, the programmer has to do extra work to track the lines/2nd field, handling partial line reads where the 2nd field itself may be incomplete etc..  It's not rocket science anyway, but memory mapping is considerably easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iostream as others have suggested.  Another way to go would be to simply use fscanf.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

...

FILE* fp = fopen(path_to_file, "r");
char[256] data;

while(fscanf(fp, "%*s<tab>%s<tab>%*s<tab>%*s", data))
{
   do what you want with your data
}
```

Comment: Why the stars?  Or, why the stars outside the `%s`?  Using `%*s` suppresses the assignment.  The downside is that `%s` stops at the first white space, so if there are blanks in the data, this won't work directly.  You could use `%100*[^\t]` to suppress data1, and `%100[^\t]` to capture data2, etc, but the lengths are error prone.

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that.  I've updated the code to have the *s in the right places.  Yeah it'll only work if the data doesn't have whitespace

Comment: If you're going to recommend ancient C functions instead of the C++ Standard Library, you should at least explain why you think they have any benefits... and don't leak memory in the process.